# Testing if array contains at least one object that has some property

Tags: ios, swift, testing

I want to test if the given array contains at least one object that contains a specific 'string' in it. Is it useful and possible?

Comment: Add some code what you've tried till now.

Answer (score 1):

Try `filter()`.

```
struct S { let string: String }

let array = [ S(string: "a"), S(string: "b") ]

let hasAtleastOneA = array.filter({ $0.string == "a" }).count > 0
```

Comment: Can I do something like this in Unit Testing (not in regular code)? :)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with doing that in _any_ code.  If you have a large array and expect the element near the beginning, you might want an approach that lets your bail early, but otherwise, this works everywhere.

Comment: okay never mind :)

Answer (score 0):

something like this :

```
let array = ["a","b","c"]

if array.count > 0 {
    for name in array {
        if name.contains("a"){
            print("YES")
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the outer `if`, and you should exit the loop early, if found.

Answer (score 0):

You check do this way,

```
let filtered = data.filter({$0.contains("test")})
```

[Reference Higher order functions in swift: Filter, Map, Reduce, flatmap](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/higher-order-functions-in-swift-filter-map-reduce-flatmap-1837646a63e8)